# Update library: Boost on Debian 7

Tags: linux, unix, boost, debian

I am a newbie on unix systems and I've currently a problem with libs updates.
I don't know really how to update the library [Boost](http://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_55_0.html) to the version 1.55

I tried this way but the boost system version returns 1.48.

```
$ wget
http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/boost/boost/1.55.0/boost_1_55_0.tar.gz
$ gunzip boost_1_55_0.tar.gz
$ tar xvf boost_1_55_0.tar
```

I also tried `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade`
Then i got some errors:

> Get:1 http://http.debian.net wheezy-backports Release.gpg [1,554 B]
>   Hit http://ftp.debian.org wheezy/main i386 Packages Hit
>   http://ftp.debian.org wheezy/main Translation-en Get:2
>   http://http.debian.net wheezy-backports Release [161 kB] Get:3
>   http://http.debian.net wheezy-backports/main amd64 Packages [606 kB]
>   Get:4 http://http.debian.net wheezy-backports/main i386 Packages [607
>   kB] Err http://ppa.launchpad.net wheezy/main Sources   404  Not Found
>   Err http://ppa.launchpad.net wheezy/main amd64 Packages   404  Not
>   Found Get:5 http://http.debian.net wheezy-backports/main
>   Translation-en [376 kB] Err http://ppa.launchpad.net wheezy/main i386
>   Packages   404  Not Found Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net wheezy/main
>   Translation-en_GB Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net wheezy/main
>   Translation-en Fetched 1,752 kB in 1s (896 kB/s) W: Failed to fetch
>   http://ppa.launchpad.net/boost-latest/ppa/ubuntu/dists/wheezy/main/source/Sources
>   404  Not Found
>
> W: Failed to fetch
>   http://ppa.launchpad.net/boost-latest/ppa/ubuntu/dists/wheezy/main/binary-amd64/Packages
>   404  Not Found
>
> W: Failed to fetch
>   http://ppa.launchpad.net/boost-latest/ppa/ubuntu/dists/wheezy/main/binary-i386/Packages
>   404  Not Found
>
> E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old
>   ones used instead. root@vps299256:~# apt-get update && apt-get upgrade
>   E: Type 'https://packages.debian.org/fr/wheezy/libboost-dev' is not
>   known on line 3 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list E: The list of
>   sources could not be read.

Comment: I dont understand what u're telling to me lol

Comment: The ppa.launchpad.net may have worked once. Now epmpty. Some "ppa" are only available for a short time. ... And ppa.launchpad.net/boost-latest/ppa/ubuntu/dists is an Ubuntu repo, not supposed to be used. Please disable the disturbing lines in `/etc/apt/sources.lists` and `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/[unknown].list`

Comment: I found no solution for boost-1.55 so far. Except for a manual build. ... Or upgrade to Debian 8.4 Jessie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debian 7.11 Wheezy - amd64. Building the 55 libboost1.55 packages :

/etc/apt/sources.lists ... added two lines :

```
deb-src http://ftp.dk.debian.org/debian/ jessie main
deb-src http://ftp.dk.debian.org/debian/ jessie/updates main
```

The build-deps ( Summary of 'apt-get build-dep', and then some ) :
`# apt-get install g++ fakeroot dctrl-tools libbz2-dev libicu-dev mpi-default-dev bison flex docbook-to-man help2man xsltproc doxygen python-all-dev python3 python3-all-dev debhelper dpkg-dev` ... And from [wheezy-backports] : `dh-python`

Building boost-1.55 in /home/[name]/tmp/boost_1.55/ :

$ `apt-get -b source boost1.55=1.55.0+dfsg-3` ... and the libboost 1.55 packages for Debian 7 are created.

---

The packages (112.5MB) are uploaded as `libboost1.55_debian-7.11.tar` https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNeGFRZFF6S0g5N3M/view?usp=sharing ... Download, untar with `tar xvf libboost1.55_debian-7.11.tar` , `cd libboost1.55_debian-7.11/`, and install with # `dpkg -i *.deb`